# Matriz do Numpy

Tags: python-3.x, array, numpy, processamento-de-imagens, tensorflow

Tenho seguido o tutorial do Tensorflow para fazer um classificador de imagens, e tudo tem seguido tranquilamente até chegar nesse trecho de código:

```py
train_data = np.load(open('bottleneck_features_train.npy','rb'))
train_labels = np.array([0] * (nb_train_samples / 2) + [1] * (nb_train_samples / 2))

validation_data = np.load(open('bottleneck_features_validation.npy', 'rb'))
validation_labels = np.array([0] * (nb_validation_samples / 2) + [1] * (nb_validation_samples / 2))
```

o valor de nb_train_samples é 2000, enquanto o valor de nb_validation_samples é 800

ao chegar nesse trecho recebo o seguinte error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/workspaces/Thumb_Classifier/thumb.py", line 72, in <module>
    train_top_model()
  File "/workspaces/Thumb_Classifier/thumb.py", line 50, in train_top_model
    train_labels = np.array([0] * (nb_train_samples / 2) + [1] * (nb_train_samples / 2))
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

Já tentei usar o valor das variaveis direto, o valor delas dividadas, mas ambos os casos resultam em um error diferente e que foge do escopo do problema, já que ao alterar essas linhas o error não é lançado mais pelo numpy e sim pelo tensorflow

esse é o repo com o código do tutorial: https://gist.github.com/fchollet/f35fbc80e066a49d65f1688a7e99f069

Fico no aguardo de qualquer ajuda!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em Python, o resultado de uma divisão é do tipo float

```
>>> 2000 / 2
1000.0
```

Transforme o resultado da divisão em inteiro fazendo conforme abaixo:

```
train_labels = np.array([0] * int((nb_train_samples / 2)) + [1] * int((nb_train_samples / 2)))
```

Não esqueça de fazer o mesmo para o `validation_labels`